# Problem with Flask app running python script through Subprocess, refreshing values through AJAX

Tags: python, ajax, flask, subprocess

My first question after signing up to StackOverflow and trying many things...

I've got a Flask app with 3 files (code will be at the end of this post):

1. **EXTERNAL PYTHON SCRIPT:** Generating random alphanumeric every 5 to 10 seconds.
2. **FLASK APP:** with a route to run the above EXTERNAL PYTHON SCRIPT using PIPE.Subprocess and getting the values from it using stdout (plus - for testing - I'm also getting the same values printed in the terminal so I know this part works)
3. **HTML FILE:** with AJAX to refresh whatever was generated through FLASK APP / EXTERNAL PYTHON SCRIPT every 1 second. *And after many, MANY tries => can't get it to work on the website while values are definitely available because I can see them in the terminal when running the same Flask app.*

I'd like it to:

1. Display the values generated through EXTERNAL PYTHON SCRIPT in FLASK APP one under the next one as they come.

**Obviously this is not "art for art's sake" but rather => I've got a larger script that could benefit from this simplification: displaying the values generated by the external script within the flask app using AJAX.**

CODE:

1. **EXTERNAL PYTHON SCRIPT:**

```
import random
import string
import time

def generate_random_value():
    while True:
        value = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, k=1))
        print(value)
        time.sleep(random.randint(5, 10))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    generate_random_value()
```

2. **FLASK APP:**

   ```
   from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
   from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

   app = Flask(__name__)

   @app.route('/')
   def index():
       return render_template('index.html')


   @app.route('/values')
   def values():
       def generate_values():
           process = Popen(['python', '-u', 'random_generator.py'], stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True)
           for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, ''):
               value = line.rstrip() #+ '<br>'
               print(value)  # Print value in the terminal
               yield value
               # return value 
       return Response(generate_values(), mimetype='text/html')



   if __name__ == '__main__':
       app.run()
   ```

   **return value**  instead of **yield value** ====>>>> it partially, works with return instead of yield but I don't know why? NEVERTHELESS:

   => it generates only one value at a time (rather than writing them one by one under each other)

   => and it displays >>>some<<< value every 1 second (as the refresh rate of AJAX in html) while the EXTERNAL PYTHON SCRIPT generates value every 5 to 10 seconds.
3. **HTML FILE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Random Values</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/values',
            success: function(response) {
                $('#output').append(response);
            },
            complete: function(response) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    window.location.reload(true);
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
      });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Random Values:</h1>
    <div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd like it to:

1. Display the values generated through EXTERNAL PYTHON SCRIPT in FLASK APP one under the next one as they come / are generated.

As I mentioned above: I tried replacing yield with return and it (sort of) works but

1. it generates only one value at a time (rather than writing them one by one)
2. and it displays some value every 1 second (as the refresh rate of AJAX in html) while the EXTERNAL PYTHON SCRIPT generates value every 5 to 10 seconds.

**Obviously this is not "art for art's sake" but rather => I've got a larger program that could benefit from this simplification that I'm testing here: displaying the values generated by the external script within the flask app using AJAX.**

Comment: You should look into [Server-Sent Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) or [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket)